# read from one file, modify and output to another file in java

Tags: java, file

The assignment is to read a file, create a new file that matches the input file but has numbers lines added

I have several examples to copy from.  I have tried new File(), new FileReader() and BufferedReader().  I can't seem to get any data out of the input file

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Hw1_43 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        // Prompt user for input file name
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter input file name: ");
        String inputFileName = in.next();  // instantiate input file name for later use
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(inputFileName));

        //ArrayList<String> line = new ArrayList();
        int counter = 0;
        while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = inputFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(counter + line);
            counter ++;
        }


        System.out.println(inputFileName);
    }

}
```

Also after I get the input file to read and write it into an output file, where is the output file so I can look at it to make sure it is correct?

Comment: `File file = new File(inputFileName); System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());` to see where Java is looking

Comment: If you are providing just the file name for the input and it is reading it correctly, then providing the output file name only would write the file in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

FileReader only reads from a file.  You need to create a FileWriter, which writes to a file (e.g. FileWriter outputFile = new FileWriter ("C:/tmp/output_file.txt")).  As you read from the FileWriter, prepend the line numbers to each line, then write to the FileWriter.

I recommend using BufferedReader instead of Scanner. You can then use then uses the .readLine() or .lines() methods, the latter can be streamed into a BufferedWriter.